# Extended Golay codes are self dual

Tags: cryptography, coding-theory, orthogonality

Show that extended Golay code $G_{24}$ and $G_{12}$ are self dual.

To show it have to show that any two rows of $G_{12}$ and $G_{24}$ are orthogonal, that is inner product of any two rows are zero.

In this way we get $G_{24} \subset G_{24}^\perp$ and $G_{12}\subset G_{12}^\perp$
and as they are of same dimension so $G_{24}= G_{24}^\perp$ and $G_{12}= G_{12}^\perp$.

But I cannot understand how to prove that any two rows of both the codes are orthogonal.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What definition do you have for Golay codes? The proof will depend on how you describe a Golay code.

Comment: In the case of the extended binary Golay code $G_{24}$, this amounts to saying that any two vectors in the code have an even number of 1's in common.  If you know that $G_{24}$ is a doubly even code (i.e. every code word has Hamming weight a multiple of 4), then this follows from that.  (Compare the Hamming weight of $a+b$ to those of $a$ and $b$.)  In any case, you can see proofs in Robin Chapman's survey here:  http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/golay11.pdf

Answer (score 0):

For Extended golay code the generator matrix G=[I,B]
where I is 12x12 identity matrix.
Hope u know B a 12x12 Matrix.

To prove this code as orthogonal
B^T=B, then **B.B^T=I** (Orthogonal).